# Is it possible to retrieve Facebook Pages information like notes, photos, and videos?

Tags: api, facebook

I've been up and down the [Facebook API](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API) as well as all over the internets looking for an answer to this question.

Has anyone seen an example of a website that displays information pulled from a Facebook Page? Is this even possible?

I've been able to run the demos provided at [Trying Out Facebook Connect](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Trying_Out_Facebook_Connect) and the [API Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php), but I've only been able to retrieve information on users not pages.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it doesn't appear possible. Quote from [Stream.get](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.get):

> This method returns an object (in JSON-encoded or XML format) that contains the stream from the perspective of a specific viewer -- currently, a user, and in the near future, a Facebook Page.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried it out on the console - it does work with pages. You just have to use the page ID instead of the user ID for whatever you're trying to get.

Example:

```
$facebook->api_client->photos_getAlbums(5281959998,'');
```

This gets the photo albums of the page with ID 5281959998, which is the NY Times.

Comment: You're right about photos. I was using photos.get instead of photos.getAlbums, but Notes doesn't work work and Videos appears to have no helpful methods at all.